# scrot : giblib error saving to file failed

Tags: centos7

I have installed `Scrot` on `Centos 7`,

```
giblib error saving to file ***.png failed
```

occurs for

```
scrot -s
```

Help for a solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have the same problem in Ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

Are you telling `scrot` to save to an explicit file? 
Several things can go wrong:

- you target a file that has an unsupported extensions. `scrot -s asdf` doesn't work. `scrot -s asdf.png` does.
- I've seen `scrot` examples with quotes in the output. Special characters can mean trouble within quotes, for example `~`. `scrot ~/asdf.png` works, `scrot "~/asdf.png"` doesn't work. Single quotes do not work either. That's the same as with `mv`, special character expansion. This gives a giblib error, which is a little confusing.

If this is your problem, do not to use quotes, use absolute pathes, or let `scrot` create its default file and move it afterwards as described [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=71008):

```
scrot -e 'mv $f ~/Pictures/screenshots'
```